# Mysql schema relationships

Tags: database, schema

I was searching on the internet but I could not find the exact answer for my question even tough it is very basic.

I have decided to do simple database using MySQL and I am a little bit confused about the schema. I want to have Entity Client - which may have or may not have many Events. Event can not exist without Priority, Client and Status. Priority, Status and Client can exist without Event.

Is my database scheme correct ? If I understood it correctly the circle near opposite entity means that it is not mandatory for priority or client or status to exist without. Thanks for helping.

[image]

Comment: The structure of the schema is fine, just make the foreign key columns on the `Event` table not nullable, which will prevent the creation of an Event without a selected State and Priority. There is nothing stopping priorities and states from being created independently.

Comment: Thank you Chris !